# ArrayList vs HashSet

Tags: java, data-structures

I was working on this problem https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1660, and here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class SubarraySumsI {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    int N = in.nextInt();
    int X = in.nextInt();
    
    ArrayList <Long> prefix = new ArrayList <Long> ();
    int count = 0;
    prefix.add(0l);
    long prefixsum = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
        prefixsum += in.nextInt();
        prefix.add(prefixsum);
        
        if (prefix.contains(prefixsum - X)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(count);
    in.close();
  }
}
```

I noticed that on a lot of the test cases, it was really slow. However, if I just change prefix from an ArrayList to a HashSet, it suddenly becomes a lot faster.

I'm not that experienced with using Sets and HashSets yet, so can someone explain what the difference is between ArrayList and HashSet?

Answer (score 0):

You can read in here the difference between `Set` and `Array`

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-list-set-and-map-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

The question that you asked

> "Can someone explain what the difference is between ArrayList and HashSet?"

is too broad.  There are many differences, and you should be able to find many resources that summarize them.

The (probable) specific thing that is causing a performance difference in your program will be this:

```
 if (list.contains(prefixsum - X)) {
        count++;
 }
```

versus (presumably)

```
 if (set.contains(prefixsum - X)) {
        count++;
 }
```

In the `ArrayList` case, the `contains` method has to test each element of the list until it either find a match or reaches the end.  The time taken to do that will typically be proportional to the number of elements in the list.

In the `HashSet` case, a hash table data structure is used which (typically) reduces the number of elements that need to be tested to a small number.

The net result is that `contain` is fast for a `HashSet` and slow for `ArrayList`.

Explaining in detail how hash tables work in general and specifically in the `HashSet` case is beyond the scope of this Q&A.